# Laravel 5.3 - From submiting by clicking fast

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Hi every one i have on problem when i **click faster on button the form submitting** so many time and in data base i have repeated records.

> I try to **solve** the problem by adding **JavaScript** to disable the button when it's clicked one time. But i need other solution !!

**JavaScript** can **disabled by the navigateur** or something like this.

Please if someone got the best solution tell me.

Thank you

Comment: You can use a check if same data(already exists) goes 2nd time it should redirect back

Comment: Disabling the button JavaScript side seems the right way to do it in my opinion. You could also limt the incoming requests from your server, take a look at Rate Limiting and throttling